# How can I solve the vertical alignment with a CH2 and a ring?

Tags: xetex, chemfig

I draw a picture like this:
[image: Bad]
You may find that the right side of the molecule is under the base line. I know this problem is 'Vertical alignment' mentioned in P25 of the offical documantaion. After I place `\chemskipalign` in front of the first ring, the problem is fixed, but an unpleasent blank occured:
[image: Unpleasent blank]
Here is my code:

First:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\setatomsep{1.5em}

\begin{document}

something
\(
\chemfig*{CH_3-*6(-=-(-CH_2-*6(-=-(-CH_2-*6(-=-(-CH_3)=-=))=-=))=-=)}
\)
something

\end{document}
```

Second:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\setatomsep{1.5em}

\begin{document}

something
\(
\chemfig*{CH_3-\chemskipalign*6(-=-(-CH_2-*6(-=-(-CH_2-*6(-=-(-CH_3)=-=))=-=))=-=)}
\)
something

\end{document}
```

What can I do?

Comment: What is the "unpleasant blank"? Sorry if I'm just going blind this morning, but the only difference I see between the two screenshots is the corrected vertical alignment.

Comment: @PaulGessler, The first atom of the first ring. In the first picture, it is connected by 3 lines, and in the second picture, there is a blank.

Comment: Absolutely right! (So I am going slightly blind this morning :-).) Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can locally redefine `\printatom` in order to force atom depths to 0pt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setatomsep{1.5em}
\begin{document}
something
\(
\renewcommand\printatom[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}\dp0=0pt \box0 }
\chemfig{CH_3-*6(-=-(-CH_2-*6(-=-(-CH_2-*6(-=-(-CH_3)=-=))=-=))=-=)}
\)
something
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that is quite unbelievable. Can I use it gloabally? Are the solution safe in most cases?

Comment: No, don't use it globaly because the bond in `\chemfig{\CH_3-[7]-CH_3}` becomes misplaced. There is no general solution. In your case, you could also try `\def\X{\chemskipalign\vphantom{A}}
\chemfig{CH_3|\X-*6(-=-(-CH_2|\X-*6(-=-(-CH_2|\X-*6(-=-(-CH_3)=-=))=-=))=-=)}`. Ah I forgot: what is "unbelievable"?

Comment: I am the author of chemfig and I tell you it is preferable NOT to use it globally.

Comment: I believe the author must use the attribute `depth` for some reason, but you just force it to 0pt, and it works, which is unbelievable. By the way, I think making it gloabally may be the best. Because in `something
\chemfig*{CH_3CH_2-[:60,,3]C(-[:120]H_3C)=C(-[:-60]H)-[:60]C|{(CH_3)_3}CH_2-[:-60]C(-[:-120]H)=C(-[:60]H)(-[:-60]H)}
something`, the default result is more unbearable than yours, and I can avoid it by choose a carborn to link instead of a hydrogen. Carborn usually have no subscript or superscript. Sorry, I just click the enter befor I complete my comment, and, no offense.

Comment: I'd prefer `\renewcommand\printatom[1]{\sbox{0}{$\mathrm{#1}$}\dp0=0pt \box0 }`. There's no point in using `\ensuremath` for something you *know* must be in math mode. And `\sbox{0}` is safer than `\setbox0=\hbox`

Answer (score 0):

I have a successful attempt, but it is not elegant enough.
[image: Successful, but not elegant enough]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\setatomsep{1.5em}

\newcommand{\vr}{{\tikz \draw[draw=none] (0,0) rectangle (0,\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`A);}}
\begin{document}

something
\(
\chemfig*{CH_3|\vr-*6(-=-(-CH_2|\vr-*6(-=-(-CH_2|\vr-*6(-=-(-CH_3)=-=))=-=))=-=)}
\)
something

\end{document}
```

I try to put the character `|` into the command `\vr`, but fail. It cannot get the result expected. Can anyone help me to achieve it?